# Log off windows using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, windows

I'm making an application in VBA and after 15 or so minutes of inactivity, the program opens a seperate userform and starts counting down from 60. After that time has expired, I wish to make windows log off so that any data won't get compromised by students or nothing gets destroyed. However; after spending nearly an hour going through forums and my textbook, I can't find a functioning, simple piece of code. Any snippets or suggestions are welcome :)

Thank you very much :)

Comment: See [ExitWindowsEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Winuser/nf-winuser-exitwindowsex).

Comment: I have but not it keeps saying invalid syntax at ExitWindowsEx?

Comment: Dim Action As Long
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Action = ExitWindowsEx(EWX_LOGOFF, 0&)
    Application.Quit

Comment: FYI you can [edit] your code into the question itself (and format it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use the shutdown.exe to log off.  Example below

```
Sub LogOffComputer()
'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/shutdown
    Dim oShell
    Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    oShell.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "shutdown.exe /l /f"
    Set oShell = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: the cmd.exe pops up although shutdown.exe /l /f does not fill on the command-line.

Answer (score 2):

You could just lock the workstation

```
Declare Function LockWorkStation Lib "user32.dll" () As Long
Public Sub LockPC()
    LockWorkStation
End Sub
```

**Update** You could also logoff but be aware all applications are closed and normally nothing will be saved.

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function ExitWindowsEx Lib "User32" ( _
  ByVal uFlags As Long, _
  dwReserved As Long) As Long
 
Private Const EWX_FORCE = 4
Private Const EWX_LOGOFF = 0
Private Const EWX_REBOOT = 2
Private Const EWX_SHUTDOWN = 1
Private Const EWX_POWEROFF = 8

Sub Logoff()
Dim Retval As Long

    Retval = ExitWindowsEx(EWX_LOGOFF, 0&)
    If Retval = 0 Then MsgBox "Could not log off", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Logoff"

End Sub
```

**Attention** For a **64-bit Excel** you have to adapt the **api declarations**, have a look [here](https://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/apideclarations.asp). Often you only have to add PtrSafe and replace Long with LongLong

**Update 2022/08/10** API calls for 64-bit Excel

```
Declare PtrSafe Function LockWorkStation Lib "user32.dll" () As Long

Declare PtrSafe Function ExitWindowsEx Lib "user32" _
        (ByVal uFlags As Long, ByVal dwReserved As Long) As Long
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that :)

Comment: Sorry but where would I place the different pieces of this code? Also the function statement does not work on my machine, something about updating for 64-bit architecture?

Comment: You put the code in a normal module. Do you have an 64-bit excel?

Comment: I do not succeed to adapt the api declarations for 64 bit unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

This works on my 64 bit Excel:

```
Sub shut()
Shell "Shutdown -s -t 20", vbHide
End Sub
```

Although I am looking for a method to close any running apps first, since I suppose it can make the system corrupt to close apps by shutdown windows with running apps.